# Как в ST3 ставить одинаковые кавычки (ёлочки)?

Tags: html, css, sublime-text

Как в ST3 ставить одинаковые кавычки (ёлочки)? Я копирую-вставляю, но почему-то у меня они разные:

[image: Скрин]

Цифрового блока у меня нет на клаве - вариант через alt отпадает

Comment: Кого откуда куда копируете-вставляете? У меня всё отлично работает

Comment: @andreymal Вот с этого сайта например:
https://unicode-table.com/ru/sets/quotation-marks/

Когда копирую - в саблайме они разные почему-то
http://prntscr.com/jfaew4

Comment: Всё работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmOXH.gif

Comment: @andreymal да оно то копируется, но если присмотреться они разные по размеру вставляются:
http://prntscr.com/jfai56
Не понимаю почему так их отображает саблайм

Comment: А, ну так бы в вопросе прямо и написали, что размер у кавычек не совпадает — мы тут со штангенциркулем у экрана не сидим :)

Comment: Только это уже скорее вопрос к вашей операционной системе, к вашему шрифту и алгоритму рисования в данном размере шрифта, а не в ST3. В каком-нибудь условном notepad при том же шрифте и том же размере скорее всего будет то же самое

Comment: Собственно да, в Блокноте всё то же самое, ST3 совершенно ни при чём https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu282.png

Comment: Ну и в итоге наверно данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не имеет отношения к программированию, а к системному администрированию ну ооооочень с натяжкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да попробуй просто писать через html-код:
Правая кавычка - `&raquo;` 
Левая кавычка - `&laquo;`

А по скриншоту по идее там они одинакового размера будут в итоговом документе, просто на экране возможно баг рендеринга.